# object-tag with height behaves different in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css

An empty object-tag seems to behave different in Chrome and Firefox given a css-rule with height.

A simple example can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bvar0zpb/

```
<style>
    div {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    object {
        height: 80px;
    }
</style>

<div>
   <object>
   </object>
</div>
```

It seem to help to make the object-tag a block-element, but I'm unsure if this could break any other behavior.

Anyone have a solution on this problem?

Comment: In Chrome it's exactly 80px high. What is the height in FF?

Comment: In FF it's 0px...

Answer (score 0):

Add: `object { display: block; }`

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

object {
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <object>
  
  </object>
</div>
```